# Create REST call from search query

Tags: rest, filter, folder, document-set

I have a search query web part that I am running that looks like the following.

(path:"PATH TO FOLDER" AND ContentTypeId:0x0120D520*)

This path contains links to document sets. I am trying to recreate this query in a REST call.

I've tried variations of things like the url below with no luck.

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Path to folder')/Files?$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,'0x0120D520')
```

Comment: Are you not getting any results from the rest url or search query? This url works fine api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents')/Files?$select=name&$filter=startswith(Name, 'test')

Comment: @S Merchant The folder structure is Folder > Folder > Documents sets. One top level folder on the subsite and then an inner folder which contains the document sets. I am getting a "Value does not fall within the expected range." error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items nomenclature in order to filter by ContentTypeId.